# What are some good older devices that I can scrounge i2c or spi modules from?

Tags: i2c, spi

I am a newcomer to electronics design and I'd really like to start fiddling with making my own circuits.  I have a raspberry pi which has both I2C and SPI interfaces, and I'm wondering if there's any classes of older equipment that might have these sorts of chips?

I don't have the equipment to desolder or handle surface-mount components properly, so anything I'm trying to take chips from would need to be through-hole.

I have many older computer systems laying around, I'm assuming that due to the prevalence of SMBus that there's likely some of those chips on a motherboard that could be salvaged.

Are there any better places to look for I2C or SPI chips?

Comment: You'll need something digital. You can't really be anything more specific I'm afraid (but not sure), as both protocols are very basic. Other question: why not sample new chips?

Comment: Well, I'm just starting out so I'm not really sure about sampling.  I'm not even sure if this question is on topic for this stack exchange.  I'm just a hobbyist with no formal training beyond having an amateur radio license.

Comment: I'd consider this on topic. You say you're just starting and therefore don't want to sample. It's entirely up to you, but is that a problem? I have quite a collection unused sampled chips. I may use them in the future, and it's free. But again, your choice.

Comment: It's not that I'm against it, I just don't know how to go about getting samples.  I'll have to do some research on getting them unless you know of a quick way to get a whole random assortment of goodies?

Comment: Check out microchip. They have memory chips, ideal for trying the protocol if you ask me. See the 23K256 for example. On the bottom of the product page there's a Pricing & Sampling section. If there are any problems please let me know, but now I'm going to bed

Answer (score 3):

After several years scavenging parts, I can tell you that it is difficult to find I2C or SPI through-hole chips... But, many of the devices by themselves have these communication protocols somewhat hidden. One example is the Wii Nunchuk (I2C), SD cards (SPI), some multimeters (SCI)...

My recommendation: start with some of those and then buy a simple soldering iron to scavenge SMD parts, or sample/buy. You will realize that the price of the component ($0.6?) is NOTHING compared to the time you will spend trying to make it work :D